# react-native useRoute error (Component Exception)

Tags: react-native

When declaring the useRoute() hook of React Navigation (@react-navigation/native), I get the following error message:

> **Component Exception**
>
> Couldn't find a route object. Is your component inside a screen in a
> navigator?

**Source**

```
if (route === undefined) {  
    throw new Error(            
          ^         
    "Couldn't find a route object ..."  
   ); 
}
```

I noticed the error occurs when declaring the useRoute hook

```
const route = useRoute();
```

Here's the code of my NavBar component where I want to use useRoute:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { useRoute, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Image, View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import menu from '../assets/menu.png';
import { nav } from '../styles';

const NavBar: React.FC = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const route = useRoute();

  function navigate(path: any) {
    if (path) {
      setShow(false);
      navigation.navigate(path);
    }
    setShow(false);
  }

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      activeOpacity={0.8}
      style={nav.drawer}
      onPress={() => setShow(!show)}>
      <Image source={menu} />
      {show ? (
        <View style={nav.options}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={nav.option}>
            <Text
              style={[
                nav.textOption,
                route.name == 'Home' ? nav.textActive : null,
              ]}
              onPress={() => navigate('Home')}>
              Home
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={nav.option}>
            <Text
              style={[
                nav.textOption,
                route.name == 'Catalog' ? nav.textActive : null,
              ]}
              onPress={() => navigate('Catalogo')}>
              Catalogo
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={nav.option}>
            <Text
              style={[
                nav.textOption,
                route.name == 'Adm' ? nav.textActive : null,
              ]}
              onPress={() => navigate('Home')}>
              Adm
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      ) : null}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

Here's my package.json

```
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.1.0",
"axios": "^0.21.4",
"expo": "~42.0.1",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-dom": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
"react-native-screens": "~3.4.0",
"react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
```

Comment: where are you using this `Navbar` component?

Comment: I'm using the NavBar in the Stack.Navigator in my file index.tsx (package routes)

<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerTitle:"", headerStyle:{backgroundColor:colors.primary,},
        headerLeft:()=> <HeaderText/>,
        headerRight:()=> <NavBar/>,
        }}> ...

Comment: Hey @Alexandre did you found the answer, how to use it,getting same error on my side.

Comment: Also getting this error @Alexandre did you find a solution?